# softwarerestrictions gpo and appdata locallow

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

In order to prevent accidental running of virus payloads I've added several paths to the `SoftwareRestrictions` `Group Policy` (Server 2008 R2) on our Windows Domain. The rules work fine for `appdata\roaming` and `appdata\local` but I can't seem to block executables from running in the `LocalLow` directory.

Clients are all Windows 7 Pro and the policy is linked to the Computer (not the User).

I've tried:

`%userprofile%\appdata\locallow`

`%appdata%\..\locallow`

But after updating my policy with `gpupdate /force` it still allows me to run executables there.

Any idea on how to tell the policy to apply its rules to this directory or is there some underlying mechanism that makes LocalLow 'safe' and I should not worry about it?

Comment: I don't think there should be any reason for it not to work. Since it's a computer policy did you try to restart the pc rather than just a gpupdate?

Comment: @Jon Several reboots, it just doesn't seem to like the path.

Comment: Not sure why this path is giving issues. However, at my previous job we did the same software restrictions and I believe we just blocked everything in appdata. It seems you want to do the same since you're blocking all 3 folders. So just do a %userprofile%\appdata\* to block all subfolders.

Comment: It seems the backslash after appdata does not show up in the comment. Make sure to add a "\" before the "*".

Comment: Ok, the broader appdata* does work on LocalLow. I also think I jumped at conclusions by being fooled by Windows presenting a windows saying 'The publisher could not be verified' for my testing .exe file. I incorrectly assumed that it would run and didn't try further. The same testing .exe is instantly blocked with a different message in Roaming, Local and root AppData directories. All working now, thanks.